# object of the Order class is not being instantiated

Tags: c#

Still learning c# and messing with GUI's, I ran into this problem and I have looked at the code over and over again and do not understand why my Order class will not be instantiated. Evrything looks good to me. Is there a basic concept I am missing here?

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        newOrder = new Order ();
        for (int i = 0; i < newOrder.menuEntree.Length; i++)
        {
            this.listBox.Items.Add(newOrder.menuEntree[i]);
        }
    }
    private void listBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        newOrder.Entree = this.listBox.Text;
    }
    public class Order
    {
        public string[] pastryEntree = new string[] { "Baklava", "Croissant", "Blueberry Muffin" };
        public decimal[] pastryPrice = new decimal[] { 3.00m, 2.50m, 1.75m };

        private string entree;
        private decimal entreePrice;

        public Order()
        {
            entree = "";
            entreePrice = 0;
        }

        public string Entree
        {
            get
            {
                return entree;
            }
            set
            {
                entree = value;
                SetEntreePrice();
            }
        }
        public decimal EntreePrice
        {
            get
            {
                return entreePrice;
            }
        }
        public void SetEntreePrice()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < pastryPrice.Length; i++)
            {
                if (pastryEntree[i] == entree)
                {
                    entreePrice = pastryPrice[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: this `newOrder = new Order ();` should be `Order newOrder = new Order ();`

Comment: Where is the variable `newOrder` declared ? How does the line `newOrder = new Order ();`  even compile without a type ?  It should be `Order newOrder = new Order ();`  or `var newOrder = new Order ();`

Comment: @CharlesBretana I feel dumb... Im 3 months into learning my first programming language, c#, and I still feel like I know nothing... This makes sense.

Comment: @Azzamean you should learn `C++` first. It's better for you.

Comment: @KingKing Are you trying to discourage him from programming altogether?

Comment: @Rotem No, learning `C++` will help him **understand the computer stuff better**, of course, **we just learn it at basic level**, at higher or advanced level `C++` is much more difficult than `C#`.

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined `newOrder` as a member of your `Form1` class, and so the variable is undeclared when you try to instantiate it.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Order newOrder;

    ....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to replace this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    newOrder = new Order ();
    for (int i = 0; i < newOrder.menuEntree.Length; i++)
    {
        this.listBox.Items.Add(newOrder.menuEntree[i]);
    }
}
```

with

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < newOrder.menuEntree.Length; i++)
    {
        Order newOrder = new Order ();
        this.listBox.Items.Add(newOrder.menuEntree[i]);
    }
}
```

It is likely that you want to declare order within the for-loop. Otherwise all the orders would be the same instance.

Comment: It is quite unlikely OP would want this declared in a local scope at all.